# Ubuntu won't boot after installed

Tags: 12.10, dual-boot, windows-8

I installed Ubuntu on my Compaq CQ58 (pre-installed Windows 8) with the UEFI Diabled and with a LiveUSB. I did the partitions on my pc and used 100GB for Ubuntu. Ubuntu installed and said that i had to restart so that the installation would be completed but after the restart it showed both Windows 8 and Ubuntu in the boot menu but when I tried to boot Ubuntu it didn't. How can I fix this?

Comment: So what happens after you boot into Ubuntu?

Comment: try this here http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1613132